# How is this adding a pointer and an integer

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, data-structures

this is a program from a book in C

```
#include<stdio.h>

int *fun(int *p, int n);

main()
{
    int arr[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, *ptr, n;
    n=5;
    ptr = fun(arr, n);
    printf("arr = %p, ptr = %p, *ptr = %d\n",arr,ptr,*ptr); 
}
int *fun(int *p, int n)
{
    p=p+n;
    return p;
}
```

I'm confused as to how `p=p+n` line works, as p should hold the pointer towards `arr[0]` according to me, but it adds with an integer and in output `*ptr` is `6`

Comment: lookup "pointer arithmetic"

Comment: it adds to the pointer, not to the int pointed to by the pointer. it's the same as `p = &p[n]`

Comment: OHH, got it, I was thinking the result 6 is because of 1(p's value)+5(n's value), but it is because now p is pointing to arr[5] whose value is 6

Answer (score 1):

The integer that is summed represents the element in the array at the summed value.  For example: `arr [8]` is equivalent to `* (i + 8)`, with `char * i = (char *)` arr, in this case I will jump to element `8` of the array (if for example the array is char).

Note that arrays are nothing more than pointers.